# Calling constant complexity O(1) 5 line function significantly impacts performance, why?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, arduino

I have the following code:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <ros/time.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Range.h>

#define sensNumber 3
#define firstTrigPin 3
#define firstEchoPin 9

ros::NodeHandle  nh;
sensor_msgs::Range range_msg;
ros::Publisher pub_range( "/ultrasound", &range_msg);
char frameid[] = "/ultrasound";

int trigPin=firstTrigPin;
int echoPin=firstEchoPin;

void increasepins(){
    trigPin++;
    echoPin++;
    if(trigPin>firstTrigPin+sensNumber){
        trigPin=firstTrigPin;
    }
    if(echoPin>firstEchoPin+sensNumber){
        echoPin=firstEchoPin;
    }
}

void setup(){
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(pub_range);
    for(int i=0;i<sensNumber;i++){
        pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
        increasepins();  
    }
    range_msg.radiation_type = sensor_msgs::Range::ULTRASOUND;
    range_msg.header.frame_id =  frameid;
    range_msg.field_of_view = 0.1;  
    range_msg.min_range = 0.0;
    range_msg.max_range = 6.47;
}

long range_time;

void loop()
{
    increasepins();
    //publish the adc value every 50 milliseconds
    //since it takes that long for the sensor to stablize
    long duration, distance;
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  // should be high?
    delayMicroseconds(2); // make this 20
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); // reset value?
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    distance = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH)/ 58,2; //sensor constant is 3.4

    range_msg.range = distance;
    range_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
    range_time =  millis() + 50;
    range_msg.field_of_view = trigPin; 
    range_msg.min_range = echoPin;

    pub_range.publish(&range_msg);

    nh.spinOnce();
}
```

This above code runs at my funduino at aprox 2 times a second for the whole loop. If I however remove the `increasePins` method it runs at around 100 times per second. Why the big chance? It seems like such a trivial piece of code (just increase 2 variables and then compare them) make such a large difference?

For reference we are talking about this function:

```
void increasepins(){
    trigPin++;
    echoPin++;
    if(trigPin>firstTrigPin+sensNumber){
        trigPin=firstTrigPin;
    }
    if(echoPin>firstEchoPin+sensNumber){
        echoPin=firstEchoPin;
    }
}
```

Which to me looks really simple when compared to having to wait for the echo to come back and getting the time and that sort of things required for the rest of the code.

Comment: increasepins manipulates global vars which are handed down to functions lie pinMode(). Could they be the bottleneck ?

Comment: (FWIW, there's no problem with the basic C++ - assuming the performance issue is with `loop()`, then the cause must relate to the `digitalWrite`, `pulseIn`, and/or `pub_range.publish` functions - the impact of the changed values on their operation - so their examples and documentation are the place to look....)

Comment: These are the default implementations of the arduino but they do not really seem to give me any reason as to why any particular random pin would be paster or why changing pin would affect performance.

Comment: It *could* be because repeatedly reading or writing to the same destination is faster than switching, but that's just a hunch; I know nothing about your hardware. (BTW, you have a nasty typo in `pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH)/ 58,2`, where you've written a comma instead of a period.)

Comment: @nikbdnilo it's also slow if I set the number of sensors (sensNumber) to 1. And I have fixed the bug with the wrong comma instead of period.

Comment: I'd recommend you to attempt to make the function `inline`.

Comment: You have no `main` - where is the entry point?

Comment: Within the ros/arduino frame work setup is called first after which it enters into an infinite loop of calling the loop() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that one of the problem is that if you comment the **increasePins** function in the loop, the compiler will decide to take some of the logic outside the loop. For that you need to look @ the assembly code and see what's being done inside the loop.

Another problem may be related to the pin behavior. For example, I read that "**pulseIn**" function sends a pulse to the pin and measures it's duration. You use it to pulse the "echoPin". I suspect that if you don't change the echoPin you will have a rather constant duration. However, changing the echoPin may lead to a situation where another pin's pulse duration would be longer. To test this, you can try and use `pulsePin(echoPin, HIGH, timeout)` with a timeout parameter for the case when you did not comment the **increasePins** function. I expect the loop to run faster.

So i think that the **increasePins** is not a bottleneck. I recommend making it *inline* however (could add some speedup if the compiler hasn't done this already).

Comment: Declairing trigPin and echoPin as voletile did not affect the speed of the programam without the increasePins() function (that is it was fast and remained fast).

Comment: Ah yes by controlling the timeout I appear to be able to control the speed by which the program runs (at the cost of not always completing the search).